# Using powershell to get current user context

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a powershell script running as a scheduled task.  For elevation reasons the task runs as a script user, but I really need the script to be able to determine the user that is logged in and active when the script runs (It needs to be able to copy files from their profile).

**Is there a command I can utilize to get the current user context?**

Comment: *the user that is logged in and active* - what makes you think there's only one (your script user is a current, logged in, active user)? Or that there is one at all?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Unfortunately, hacking together a way to roam the Start layout on Windows 10 is basically like trying to shoot a blade of grass that looks identical to all other blades of grass except this one might have microsoft printed on it.  I'd accept a way to get all logged in users and itinerate through them.  It would be messier, but probably still work.  Using $env:username just gives me the user account I set to run the script.

Comment: You might be able to parse the output of `qwinsta.exe`

Answer (score 0):

this may be of use for logged in users (sorry, don't know the original source)

```
$owners = @{}
Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'name = "explorer.exe"' | % {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
Get-Process -ComputerName $computer explorer | % {$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}
```

if that doesn't get what you're looking for, you might be able to utilize the event logs with this Get-LogonHistory function

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4f6815f1-2998-484c-a423-fe6507f1548c/powershell-script-to-fetch-logonlogoff-user-on-particular-server-getwinevent-geteventlog?forum=winserverpowershell

```
function Get-LogonHistory {
    param (
        [string]$comp = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [int]$Days = 7
    )

    $Result = @()
    Write-Host 'Gathering Event Logs, this can take awhile...'
    $ELogs = Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-WinLogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days) -ComputerName $comp
    if ($ELogs) {
        Write-Host 'Processing...'
        foreach ($Log in $ELogs) {
            if ($Log.InstanceId -eq 7001) {
                $ET = 'Logon'
            } elseif ($Log.InstanceId -eq 7002) {
                $ET = 'Logoff'
            } else {
                Continue
            }
            $Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Time = $Log.TimeWritten
                EventType = $ET
                User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Log.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
            }
        }
        $Result | Select Time, EventType, User | Sort Time -Descending | Out-GridView
        Write-Host 'Done.'
    } else {
        Write-Host "Problem with $comp."
        Write-Host 'If you see a "Network Path not found" error, try starting the Remote Registry service on that computer.'
        Write-Host 'Or there are no logon/logoff events (XP requires auditing be turned on)'
    }
}

Get-LogonHistory
```

*edit: here are my findings on qwinsta that Eris mentioned

```
<# all give about the same information. the first two might give more
# https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4dwqlc/crypto_tripwire_-_help_with_script/d1v0jg5?context=3
(quser) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$server = 'localhost'

# IDENTICAL
query session /server:$server
qwinsta /server:$server

# IDENTICAL
query user /server:$server
quser /server:$server

qprocess explorer.exe /server:$server
#>
```